# Who collected Dandilion's songs in written books?

Tags: polish-language, the-witcher, andrzej-sapkowski

The final chapter of *Blood of Elves* covers the beginning of Ciri's training with Yennefer, learning about magic but also many other things. One passage describes her reading, and I noticed the following sentence:

> She read *The Adversities of Loving* and *Time of the Moon*, collections of poems by the famous troubadour Dandilion.

Dandilion, of course, is a major character in the whole Witcher series, but he sings and tells stories - I don't recall any mention of him writing them down.

**Who collected Dandilion's poems in written form?** Was it he himself, or someone who listened to him many times? Is this ever mentioned in the books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it was the poet himself: Dandilion is not just a simple troubadour wandering through the countries following Geralt, he graduated with honours the Oxenfurt University, then he has spent year teaching to other students (and occasionally he returns there as a guest lecturer). This suggests that he is indeed a famous poet, well known in the world.

> He [Dandilion] knew the University grounds like the back of his hand – and no wonder, considering he had studied there for four years, then had lectured for a year in the Faculty of Trouvereship and Poetry. The post of lecturer had been offered to him when he had passed his final exams with full marks, to the astonishment of professors with whom he had earned the reputation of lazybones, rake and idiot during his studies. Then, when, after several years of roaming around the country with his lute, his fame as a minstrel had spread far and wide, the Academy had taken great pains to have him visit and give guest lectures. Dandilion yielded to their requests only sporadically, for his love of wandering was constantly at odds with his predilection for comfort, luxury and a regular income.

The book series also quotes his written memoirs "[Half a Century of Poetry](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Half_a_Century_of_Poetry)", which most likely contains a big portion of his poems.

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten about his university connection. Any chance you could add some book quotes to help support this answer?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I've placed the quote regarding his university career. There are quotes from the "Half a century..." but they are not poems, rather than his memories